# Как создать условие если в бд нет ID пользователя

Tags: php, sqlite, вконтакте, api

Код

```
elseif($body[0] == 'cmd'){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '.$from_id;
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {        
        $self = "ID: ".$row['id']."\nБаланс: ".$row['balance']."$";
    }    
}
```

Как можно создать условие такого вида:

```
if(ID пользователя нет в бд){
$self = "error";
}
```

Comment: `if(!$row['id'])`

Comment: Работает только вне цикла foreach, а мне нужно чтобы работал в цикле

Comment: работает вне цикла? У вас вне цикла даже переменной этой нету

Comment: elseif($body[0] == 'bdtestpdo'){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '.$from_id;
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        $self = "ID: ".$row['id']."\nБаланс: ".$row['balance']."$";
    }    
        if(!$row['id']){
   $db->exec("INSERT INTO users VALUES ($from_id, '2500', null, null, null)");
}
}
Данные он записывает.
Но если добавить в условие: $self = "ID: ".$row['id']."\nБаланс: ".$row['balance']."$";
То ID: (пусто) Баланс: (пусто)
Только при следующем сообщении данные выводятся.

Comment: Сделайте скалярную выборку по типу существующей, заменив * на count(*) - это вам даст количество пользователей по ID. А можно и без неё, используя совет @AntonKucenko но при условии что пользователей с одним ID только один в БД.